# Join two table without foreign key in an insert statement

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, foreign-keys

Suppose I have two tables A and B

Table A

```
name   |   age
----------------
jack   |  13
hanna  |   28
```

Table B

```
 id
-----
 1
 2
```

I want to insert in another table C the following

Table C

```
id   |  name  |  age
--------------------
1    |  jack  | 13
2    | hanna  | 28
```

I'm doing this

```
INSERT INTO C (id, name, age)
SELECT   b.id,  a.name,  a.age
FROM A a, B b
```

Intead of getting what I want, I get this :

```
id   |  name  |  age
--------------------
1    |  jack  |  13
1    |  hanna |  28
2    |  jack  |  13
2    |  hanna |  28
```

How could you resolve this ?

Comment: What is the relation between both tables?

Comment: There is no relation between the tables, this is why I'm asking for your help

Comment: what would you accept as meaningful output?

Comment: I've already mentionned what I want to get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
declare @a table (name varchar(50),age int)
Declare @b table (id int)

insert into @a 
select 'jack',13
union select 'hanna',28

insert into @b
select 1
union select 2

Select id,name,age from
(
Select a.* ,ROW_Number() over (order by name) as rn
from @a a
)x
JOIN
(
Select b.* ,ROW_Number() over (order by ID) as rn
from @b b
)y
ON x.rn=y.rn
order by ID
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you are my saver :)

Answer (score 0):

You can write this query to get the insert desired rows in table c

```
insert into #c
select id, name, age from (
 ( select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by name) as Aid, name, age from #A ) ATest
inner join (select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id) as Bid, id from #B) Btest on Aid = Bid
)
```